# GQL Query: Delete duplicate rows in GQL from the datastore viewer

Tags: google-app-engine, gql, gqlquery

I have a simple table with 3 string values.
I have discovered several duplicate rows, which are completely identical. What query should I use to delete those duplicate rows (keeping 1 safe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delete or perform updates to the datastore using GQL queries.

Note that GQL is not SQL.

You will also find these entities (there are no rows or tables in the datastore) are not identical as their keys will be different.

You need to write some code or use the interactive shell to find their keys and then delete them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there any query to display the duplicate rows in the datastore viewer?

Comment: No, GQL is very limited.  All you can do is perform a sorted query and check for duplicates in code.